# React this.state is undefined?

Tags: reactjs

I am following a beginner tutorial from Pluralsight, on form submit a value is passed to `addUser` component method and I need to push userName to `this.state.users` but I get error

```
 App.jsx:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined
```

Component

```
import React from 'react'
import User from 'user'
import Form from 'form'

class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            users: null
        }
    }
    // This is triggered on form submit in different component
    addUser(userName) { 
        console.log(userName) // correctly gives String
        console.log(this.state) // this is undefined
        console.log(this.state.users) // this is the error
        // and so this code doesn't work
        /*this.setState({
            users: this.state.users.concat(userName)
        })*/
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Form addUser={this.addUser}/>
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default Component
```

Comment: `addUser = (userName) => {`

Comment: @Andrew Why do you need to write in that way?

Comment: For autobind of the context in this function, but it's looks like incorrect here.

Comment: I know :p it's just that I prefer bind instead. It's dirty but works..

Comment: @MayankShukla, I'm not sure why error is like this instead of `Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` ?

Comment: I don't like bind, because if you have a lot of method, you will have a lot of copypast like this `this.addUser = this.addUser.bind(this)` in a constructor.

Comment: @Mr.Alien  but i think that is more each way to maintain context because in case of many function if we put all the binding inside constructor unnecessary it increases the no of lines :)

Comment: @MayankShukla Yep.. not denying :)

Comment: @Andrew error is *Cannot read property 'users' of undefined* i think .

Comment: If I write addUser = (userName) => { .... then the error is index.js:3 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./App", it breaks everything

Comment: @MayankShukla, is it mean in `this.state.users` we have this is defined, but without `state` filed?

Comment: @IvanTopić put this line in the constructor: `this. addUser = this. addUser.bind(this)` that syntax is property initializer syntax its a this is *experimental* syntax you need to use babel plugin for this.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Btw I do have Babel, I am playing with this https://github.com/krasimir/react-webpack-starter

Answer (score 125, accepted):

When you call `{this.addUser}` , it gets called, here `this` is an instance of your class(component), and thus it gives no error to you because `addUser` method does exist in your class `scope`,
but when you are under `addUser` method you are using `this` to update the `state` which exist in
the scope of class(component), but currently you are within the scope of `addUser` method and so it gives you an error as under `addUser` Scope you got nothing like state, user etc.
So to deal with this problem you need to bind `this` while you are calling `addUser` method.So that your method always knows the instance of `this`.

So the final change in your code will look like this:-

```
<Form addUser={this.addUser.bind(this)}/>
```

**OR**

---

You can bind `this` in the constructor,because it is the place when you should intialize things because constructor methods are called first when the components render to the `DOM`.

So you can do it in this way:-

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        users: null
    }
    this.addUser=this.addUser.bind(this);
}
```

And now you can call it in normal way as you did before:-

```
<Form addUser={this.addUser}/>
```

I hope this will work,And I made it clear to You.

Comment: Why constructor and render functions understand 'this' correctly, but addUser has it as undefined?

Comment: @Loreno, functions are object and have a scope for themselves. With bind(this) or function expression (lambda expression), we are defining the scope of the function to be the present class. I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: @Loreno `Component` (the defined component that contains the other HTML elements) is what calls `contstructor` and `render`, but the `Form` element within the component is what is attempting to call `addUser`, however, it doesn't contain a reference to that function. Other people suggested using the code `{ () => this.addUser() }` because this code calls `addUser` within the scope of the `render` function, meaning `this` refers to `Component` and not `Form`.

Answer (score 16):

@Vinit Raj's approaches works perfectly - tho i prefer to use the arrow function syntax like so.

```
<Form addUser={ () => this.addUser() }/>
```

Using an anonymous function like this, you don't need to bind it anywhere.

Comment: This will create a new function on every render which has performance implications. Since the function doesn't take any arguments, it would be better to declare it like this:
`<Form addUser={ this.addUser }/>` and declare add user with an arrow function like `addUser = () => ...`

Comment: The whole "this might cause performance issues" trope is a dead horse. Benchmark it to prove it instead of spreading techno-babble. How can you prove that calling `bind` on `this` is faster than creating a new arrow function? The fact is, it's probably so small that it literally cannot be detected in benchmarks. Any possible deviation between the two is vastly outweighed by the uncertainty in factors such as network latency. Use whichever is more readable, until *it actually becomes a measurable bottleneck* in your code.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer using arrow function do this. The arrow function syntax as like below

```
addUser = event => { 
    const { value }  = event.target;
    console.log("value", value);
}
```

To prevent this function being called on every render or re-render you need to

Change

```
<Form addUser={this.addUser}/>
```

To

```
<Form addUser={() => this.addUser()}/>
```

So that addUser gets called only when event is happened/triggered

Comment: It won't get called on every render unless you inline the call like `<Form addUser={this.addUser()}/>`

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the other answers explain this very well. Basically the problem is that Javascript's `this` keyword is insane (MDN very generously says it ["behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)).

The TL;DR is that `this` is not necessarily the class that the method is defined in. When you use `this.addUser` in your `<Form>` element, `this` is actually the `Form` object! I'm not sure why React does this - I can't really think why anyone would want that, but it's easy to verify. Just put `console.log(this)` in `addUser` and you'll find it is an instance of `Form`.

Anyway the solution is pretty simple - use an arrow function. Arrow functions make a copy of `this` at the point where they are defined. So if you put one in your render function, as other people have suggested:

```
<Form addUser={() => this.addUser()}/>
```

Then when `render()` is run, `this` will refer to the `Component` object, the arrow function will make a copy of it, and then when it is run it will use that copy. It's basically a shorthand for this code (and this is what people used to do before arrow functions):

```
    render() {
        const that = this; // Make a copy of this.
        return (
            <div>
            <Form addUser={function() { return that.addUser; }}/>
            </div>
            )
    }
```

Also, as other people have mentioned, creating a new function every time you call your render function might have performance implications, so it is better to capture `this` once somewhere else. I think this is a better approach than what other people have suggested:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            users: null
        }
    }
    // This is triggered on form submit in different component
    addUser = (userName) => { 
        this.setState({
            users: this.state.users.concat(userName)
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Form addUser={this.addUser}/>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

But this is my first day using React, and I normally try to avoid using languages as completely barking as Javascript, so take all this with a pinch of salt!

Comment: "this" should be marked as accepted

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but my issue was trying to access this.state before the `this.state = { ... }` call finished. Was doing something like this `this.state = { ...this.function1() }` and `function1 = () => { a: this.state.b }`. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

In your case by declaring your function as a fat arrow function you add context and remove the requirement to bind to this. This works just the same as the other solutions but makes things a lot simpler to both write and read. Just change...

```
 addUser(userName) { 
    console.log(userName) // correctly gives String
    console.log(this.state) // this is undefined
    console.log(this.state.users) // this is the error
    // and so this code doesn't work
    /*this.setState({
        users: this.state.users.concat(userName)
    })*/
}
```

to...

```
addUser = (userName) => { 
    console.log(userName) // correctly gives String
    console.log(this.state) // this is undefined
    console.log(this.state.users) // this is the error
    // and so this code doesn't work
    /*this.setState({
        users: this.state.users.concat(userName)
    })*/
}
```

And everything else can stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

A good pattern is to bind a method to the class in the constructor function. 
See
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

```
import React from 'react'
import User from 'user'
import Form from 'form'

class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            users: null
        }
  this.addUser = this.addUser.bind(this); 
  //bind functions which need access to "this"v in the constructor here. 

    }
    // This is triggered on form submit in different component
    addUser(userName) { 
        console.log(userName) // correctly gives String
        console.log(this.state) // this is undefined
        console.log(this.state.users) // this is the error
        // and so this code doesn't work
        /*this.setState({
            users: this.state.users.concat(userName)
        })*/
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Form addUser={this.addUser}/>
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default Component
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this context, so use

```
<form onSubmit={(event)=>this.addUser(event)}>
   // Inputs
</form>
addUser(event){
   event.preventDefault()
   // Code this.state 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Simpley use async in function

`addUser =async (userName) => {
   console.log(this.state.users) 
}`

this will works fine