# Searchfield to search for specific planets

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried adding a search field to search for planets. 
Can someone help me to fix this please?

The error I get is this:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    handleChange
    C:/Users/charl/Desktop/IRONHACK/Paperbox/paperbox/src/pages/Home.js:29
      26 |    }
      27 | 
      28 |    handleChange(e){ // eslint-disable-next-line

> 29 |        const planetssearchlist = this.state.planets.filter(planet => {
>            | ^  30 |             if(planet.name){
>         31 |                if(planet.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())){
>         32 |                    return true

---

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";

class Home extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            planets: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/"
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let planetslist = response.data.results;
            this.setState({planets: planetslist})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("You've made an error with the planets load charles: ",error)
        })
    }

    handleChange(e){ // eslint-disable-next-line
        const planetssearchlist = this.state.planets.filter(planet => {
             if(planet.name){
                if(planet.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())){
                    return true 
                }   
            }
            this.setState({
                planets:planetssearchlist
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (

        <div>
            <h1>Star Wars Planets</h1>

            <form>
                <input placeholder="searchbar" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
            </form>

            {
                this.state.planets.map((planet,i) => (
                        <p key={i}>{planet.name}</p>
                ))   
            }

        </div>    

        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React this.state is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998744/react-this-state-is-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

You must bind the function to component, you can use lambda function syntax to define your method:

```
handleChange = (e) => {}
```

or in constructor:

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
```

Also your `handleChange` function is not working properly. You need to setState outside of the filter function. You can find working sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-stallman-fs012?file=/src/index.js

---

Further things to do:

You are directly editing planet array in `handleChange` function. When user searches string you are removing items from `state.planets`. So when user removes search string, old planets will not be showing because of the removal.

- You need to store planets in a immutable array.
- After you did the search filter immutable array to create presentation array.
- Display presentation array in render function.

---

Also i highly recommend to checkout the documentation for **Passing Functions to Components**:https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: ok thanks! ReferenceError: Cannot access 'planetssearchlist' before initialization
is my error now! anyone that knows why?

Comment: Did you look at the code in the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-stallman-fs012?file=/src/index.js. If you did already can you update the code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an arrow function for `handleChange` method like this:

```
handleChange = (e) => {

}
```

Comment: ok thanks! ReferenceError: Cannot access 'planetssearchlist' before initialization
is my error now! anyone that knows why?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind handleChange method in constructor like :

this.handleChnage = this.handleChange.bind(this)

```
        or
```

you should use arrow function

handleChange = (e) => {
}

Comment: ok thanks! ReferenceError: Cannot access 'planetssearchlist' before initialization
is my error now! anyone that knows why?

Answer (score 0):

It is related to closure and `this` keyword in javascript, you define `handleChange` in `Home` component but you pass it as a callback for `onClick`, it is actually not called in `Home` ==> this is not context of `Home` any more.
There is 4 way you can solve this.
Using arrow function to define the function (I like this way):

```
handleChange = (event) => {}
```

Using array function in render:

```js
// other code
<form>
   <input placeholder="searchbar" type="text" onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}></input>
</form>
// other code
```

Bind the function in constructor

```js
// Other code
constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            planets: []
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
// Other code
```

Binding function in render:

```js
// other code
<form>
   <input placeholder="searchbar" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange(this)}></input>
</form>
// other code
```

Actually there is one more way that using `React.createClass`, but I'll not mentioned here because it is not JSX way.

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'planetssearchlist' before initialization: Because you are using it inside of this.state.planets.filter where the planetssearchlist have not done initialised yet , bring it outside

```js
handleChange(e){ // eslint-disable-next-line
    const planetssearchlist = this.state.planets.filter(planet => {
         if(planet.name){
            if(planet.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())){
                return true 
            }   
        }})
    // This is need to be outside of this.state.planets.filter
    this.setState({
      planets:planetssearchlist
    })
  }
```

Comment: ok thanks! ReferenceError: Cannot access 'planetssearchlist' before initialization
is my error now! anyone that knows why?

Comment: Because you are using it inside of `this.state.planets.filter` where the `planetssearchlist` have not done initialised yet , bring it outside. Please check my updated answer